# Any Android managers like iTunes available for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, sync, android

I recently got my first smartphone and its a HTC Wildfire S. In Windows, I installed DoubleTwist to manage and sync my music & video collection.

But as my primary OS is Ubuntu (11.04), are there any similar software to manage and sync my media collection to my Android phone?

And if there are any, can it also work with the Market like iTunes does? (I mean, download from the PC and automatically install them to my Android device). Or just media will also be fine.

So any recommendations anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can sync your media with apps like Banshee, but your phone must be recognized as a media player. Information about media devices is provided by the media-player-info package. Unfortunately, HTC Wildfire S is not there yet. You can help to integrate it in the next release by following instructions @ freedesktop: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/media-player-info

Please create a bug report as described and post the link here. I will be able to provide a file that you need.

As for the Market integration - I don't think there is a software you can use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will provide the link soon.. That covers the media syncing part (both audio and video, right?), but what about apps? Is it possible to sync apps also?

Comment: I created a bug report and here's the link: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45022

Answer (score 0):

This is the precise use case of the [Ubuntu One Files](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ubuntuone.android.files) and [Ubuntu One Music](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.sourceforge.subsonic.u1m) apps. The former will let you sync and manage 5GB worth of files remotely (any type) for free. The latter will let you stream your music library to your phone for $3.99 a month; for the same subscription you also get 20GB worth of file synch.

Comment: But that's not the point. I want to sync files like iTunes does (through the physical cable) and not over the air (as this will cost me data charges). So any way besides wireless?

Comment: Oh, okay. You could transfer over with a regular mini-USB cable and a file browser, a little less convenient though.

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way of doing that... Thanks for your answer anyway (I haven't though much about Ubuntu One Music before :)).